# Allow access to the specific IP addresses which starts with specific series using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have my own shared server where my sites are hosted. Planning to consolidate/maintain all commonly used files like images, css, js etc., as different sub-domain. For that domain, i want to deny the other users to access those files (preventing hotlinking). All my website IP addresses are starting with 208.***.***.** series. How to achieve the result?

Here are my basic htaccess lines,

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)$ - [F]
```

Kindly share your ideas. TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can add another condition:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^208\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)$ - [F]
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. let me check & comment... ":)